# How to get a JSON title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Here is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("json.js", function(result){
            $.each(result, function(i, field){

                var firstName = field.firstName;
                var lastName = field.lastName;

         $(".a").append(firstName + lastName);      
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>
<br>    
<p class="a"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Then here is my json.js code

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

When I run the program, it is nothing to show , how should I solve the problom ,Thanks

I want to show result about  John Doe Anna Smith  Peter Jones

Many Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you tried using your browser's JavaScript debugger?

Comment: "JSON title"? Please make your title clearer. Try looking at other question titles for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime I run into these problems I would console.log(result) and see how the data is getting sent back to me through the console. I used MAMP to point at my file since opening index.html in the browser won't load the JSON data. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("json.js", function(result){
            $.each(result.employees, function(i, field){
                var firstName = field.firstName;
                var lastName = field.lastName;

                $(".a").append(firstName + " " + lastName);      
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Through console.log-ing, all you needed was add .employees for it to work. Hope this helps!